# Постановка дефиса: "бизнес-Фэн Шуй"

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли написано: "бизнес-Фэн Шуй"? Смущает тот факт, что дефис, получается, относится только к слову "Фэн". То, что "Фэн Шуй" пишется в два слова - это точно.

Answer (score 1):

~ 1. Фен-шуй пишется через дефис.  "Это точно". ©
~ 2. В ситуациях, когда по общему правилу требуется дефис, но одна часть (обычно вторая) состоит более чем из одного слова с раздельным написанием, то дефис заменяется на тире.
~ 3. Написаний с более чем одним дефисом рекомендуется сколь возможно избегать. Поэтому, полагаю, написание Бизнес -- фэн-шуй будет вполне уместным.

Comment: Я работаю в эзотерической газете 10 лет, и все эти 10 лет общаюсь с Мастерами Фэн Шуй, профессоналами высокого класса. Уж им-то виднее, как действительно правильно пишется это слово. Так что, давайте тут не спорить.

Comment: Не ответил тогда - сейчас смешно читать. Если "мастерам" виднее, сем филологам, как пишется то или иное слово, может им, мастерам, профессию сменить?

Answer (score 1):

ИНТЕРЕСНОЕ ПРОТИВОСТОЯНИЕ Мастеров Фэн Шуй и русского правописания. Я попробую изложить точку зрения второй стороны, но  очень интересно было бы услышать ОБОСНОВАНИЕ версии Мастеров. А может быть, существует особые правила "феншуй-орфографии"?

1) Словарь на Грамоте.ру дает слитное написание слова "феншуй" со строчной буквы, что соответствует принципам русской орфографии. Да и вообще такая форма удобно для этого понятия, если мы собираемся сочетать его с приложением (или считать его приложением).

2) Более удачным является название «феншуй-бизнес», которое ПОДДЕРЖИВАЕТСЯ также такими терминами, как  феншуй-талисман, феншуй-здоровье, феншуй-амулет. В этом случае несклоняемое слово «феншуй» стоит на первом месте и является приложением /определением для  существительного.  Это БИЗНЕС В СООТВЕТСТВИИ С ФЕНШУЙ. Здесь очень желательно остановиться на единой форме.

3) Вариант «бизнес-феншуй»  грамматически также возможен, но он соотносится с устоявшимися сочетаниями «бизнес-план, бизнес-проект" и может пониматься неверно, а именно:  БИЗНЕС В ОБЛАСТИ ФЕНШУЙ, где феншуй – это  коммерция для вас.

Comment: Не "словарь на Грамоте", а конкретно Лопатин. один из всех. Но я ведь, помнится, тоже по Лопатину проверял.  Интересно, они поменяли, что ли, написание этого слова? Вообще "Грамота" стала страдать нестандартными решениями. ))))

Answer (score 0):

а вы уверены в том, что фэн-шуй пишется в два слова? Потому как орфографический словарь думает по-другому: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%F4%FD%ED+%F8%F3%E9

и если верить ему, то тогда написание бизнес-фэн-шуй будет достаточно уместным. Ну, а если вас такой вариант не очень устраивает, то есть правило, при котором распространенное приложение присоединяется с помощью тире: бизнес – фэн шуй.